# Sum every 3 elements of an array in ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

Is there any efficient and short way to sum every 3 elements of an array?

```
ar = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
sum_ar = [6, 15, 16]
```

first 3 elements `1+2+3=6`
    
    next 3 elements `4+5+6=15`
    
   next 3 elements  `7+8+1=15`
    
    ...
    
    if there are only two elements left, sum them

I could do something like this:

```
y=0
s=ar.size/3
((0..s).step(3).to_a).each do |i|
    sum_ar[y]=ar[i..i+2].inject(:+)
    y=y+1
end
```

but then I will miss the elements in case of such an array, where the size is not an exactly multiply of a 3:

```
ar=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A short way with [`Enumerable#each_slice`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].each_slice(3).map { |e| e.inject(:+) } # => [6, 4]
```

Comment: This is great, too, since it returns a new array. No need to have extra steps for calling `sum_arr = Array.new`

Comment: one more question: how do I map each sum back to the those 3 arrays? so, that my initial ar=[6,6,6,4]. Each element correspond to the sum, to which it contributed.

Comment: @Tonja: Ideally that should be a new question but `[1, 2, 3, 4].each_slice(3).flat_map { |e| Array.new(e.length, e.inject(:+)) }` is a possible solution.

Comment: Or `[1, 2, 3, 4].each_slice(3).flat_map { |e| e.fill(e.inject(:+)) }`.